# Textbox not getting enabled disabled in IE8

Tags: html, asp.net

I have used a simple textbox, which is not working in IE 8. By default my textbox is disabled and when I click check on the checkbox, it should get enabled. But my textbox is not only getting enabled and disabled.

Please see the textbox property for your reference:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" class="txtfld-popup1" MaxLength="5"
  onkeypress="if(event.keyCode<48 || event.keyCode>57)event.returnValue=false;"
  Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:CheckBox ID="chkInvestmentLoan" runat="server" CssClass="check"
  OnChange="javascript:enableTextBox();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  function enableTextBox() {
    if (document.getElementById("chkCropLoan").checked == true)
      document.getElementById("txtAmount").disabled = false;
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the checkbox markup and where is the code that makes your textbox enabled?

Comment: JS code:  <script type="text/javascript">
        function enableTextBox() { if (document.getElementById("chkCropLoan").checked == true)
                document.getElementById("txtAmount").disabled = false;</script>
Checkbox: <asp:CheckBox ID="chkInvestmentLoan" runat="server" CssClass="check" OnChange="javascript:enableTextBox();" />

Comment: Please don't forget to accept an answer, and upvote if you haven't already. You can do so by clicking the checkmark sign under the voting arrows to the left of an answer. If you need further information on how this works, see the [faq].

Answer (score 3):

1. Your function is missing a closing brace `}`

   ```
   function enableTextBox() {
       if (document.getElementById("chkCropLoan").checked == true)
           document.getElementById("txtAmount").disabled = false;
   }
   ```
2. The ID is different from your markup

   ```
   <asp:CheckBox ID="chkInvestmentLoan" />
   ```

   vs:

   ```
   document.getElementById("chkCropLoan")
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is that you're missing the `}` to close the function in your javascript.

If you turn on your browser's development tools using F12, then this would be obvious for you.
I personally recommend [FireBug](https://getfirebug.com/) running under FireFox.

---

As a side note, something you should be aware of with ASP.NET...

If you disable a textbox through ASP.NET (using `txtAmount.Enabled = false;`) then the value in the textbox will **always** be the original value on the post-back.  It doesn't matter whether you enable the textbox on the client, ASP.NET knows it was original disabled, so it keeps it disabled.

In order to bring back the value, I would recommend you also have a `<asp:HiddenField>` control, an update the value in that whenever you change the textbox.  Then use the value of the hidden field on your post-back.